# std::merge merging two std::vector coredump

Tags: c++, stl, merge

the following code ends up with a core dump.
What do I do wrong?

```
std::vector<int> a;
a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(4);
a.push_back(7);
std::vector<int> b;
b.push_back(2);
b.push_back(5);
b.push_back(8);
std::vector<int> c;
c.clear();


std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), c.begin());
for (it=c.begin(); it!=c.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << endl;
```

Is  there any other merging function in the stl or in boost that I could be using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that your `c` is empty because it was initialised with no elements, not to mention the unnecessary call to `clear()`. `std::merge()` takes an *output iterator* as its last argument. If `c.begin()` refers to the beginning of a `std::vector` that *already* contains enough elements, then this isn’t a problem—those elements will just be overwritten. As it is, you’re invoking undefined behaviour by writing values into memory *past* the end of the vector.

To ensure that `c` has enough space for the elements, you could do this:

```
c.resize(a.size() + b.size());
std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), c.begin());
```

However, it is more idiomatic to use a `std::back_insert_iterator`, an output iterator that calls `push_back()`. For better efficiency, you can call `reserve()` on the vector beforehand. This ensures that `c` only needs to allocate memory once, rather than as it grows during the call to `std::merge()`. The final solution looks like this:

```
#include <iterator>

// ...

c.reserve(a.size() + b.size());
std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(c));
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I would not use the term `reserve`, as it means something entirely different from `resize`.

Comment: Why did you choose to call the second solution “better”? I’d say the opposite since the size is known and the first variant is certainly more efficient and not really more complex than the second.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: the second one is less error-prone, and more general, you may know the size in this case, but sometimes you don't.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The most efficient way would be to use `reserve` and `back_insert_iterator`: no successive allocations/copies, no useless default construction (even though this is not an issue here since the elements are mere integers).

Comment: @LucTouraille: Thanks. Have edited with more information to clarify.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I wasn’t done editing my answer, sorry. I’m in the habit of answering as quickly as possible, then editing to improve and add more detail.

Comment: @Luc The `back_inserter` variant still has to call `push_back` which in turn needs to check the length (redundantly, now). I don’t know where the break-even is but I’m pretty sure that this means the `reserve` variant is still faster for primitive types.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes, calling `resize()` is *probably* more efficient for `int`, despite the zero-initialisation. I wouldn’t assert so outright without profiling, though, and I’d definitely consider it an optimisation regardless.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's right, I never thought about the overhead of the test for capacity; `resize` should indeed probably be faster for primitive types. [Mandatory comment about writing readable code first, profiling then, and only eventually considering such micro-optimizations]

Answer (score 4):

```
std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(c));
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The thing is that if you pass `c.begin()`, the merge function will start writing values into `*c.begin()`, `*(c.begin() + 1)` etc, which leads to undefined behavior, including core dump. You have two options here.

- Make sure `c` is large enough to hold all the values that merge is going to write into it. For example, you could call `c.resize(a.size()+b.size());` prior to calling `merge`
- Pass an `std::back_insert_iterator`. The example of it is given in the beginning on my answer. Every time you do `*it = x` where `it` is a `back_insert_iterator`, it will  `push_back` x into the underlying container.

Info on back insert iterator can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_insert_iterator/). `back_inserter` is just a convenience function so that you don't write a lot of template arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to store the results in `c`, which is empty, and as such, it doesn't have enough space to store them all (in fact, it doesn't have enough space to store *anything*). Try to use `back_insert_iterator`, which will `push_back` the elements instead:

```
std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

`c` isn't big enough to hold the merge.  Try:

```
#include <iterator>
...
std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(),
           b.begin(), b.end(),
           std::back_inserter(c));
```